# Getting Intellij to link sources between OSGI/Tycho modules

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, osgi, tycho

I have a large osgi project with many bundles/modules that I'm trying to get working with Intellij. Currently users edit `MANIFEST.MF` files in each bundle to manage dependencies and tycho is used to populate the `pom.xml` files that actually build the project. The target platform is built by maven as a p2 repository.

I've loaded this project into Intellij as a bunch of maven modules in a single project that each have an OSGI facet. At this point everything works pretty well, but I can't get Intellij to resolve sources between bundles.

Concretely, I have two modules in my project, `A` and `B`, and `B` references a class in `A`. `B`'s manifest imports the package from `A` that contains the class. When I 'jump to definition' on the class from `A` within `B` it takes me to the decompiled class file, rather than the sources in module `A`. When have multiple maven modules without tycho in an Intellij project however this resolution occurs automatically.

I'd like to be able to resolve sources between such modules when they are built through tycho.

Comment: 6.5 years later, have you found any solution? I am in the same situation today, because IDEA still hates Tycho.

Comment: @kriegaex Actually I would say that Tycho hates the world, in maven they redefine every basic task of maven, Tycho uses maven almost only for its lifecycle. No wonder other tools struggle with it.